# How to get rid of automatically added library provided by GCC?

Tags: gcc, linker, ubsan

I'm compiling main.c file by gcc with enabled sanitizer option.

As a result, linker command contains "-lubsan" option in its arguments list.

Need to say, that I haven't provided "-lubsan" option to gcc explicitly.

Moreover, I'm against of using it.

So, the question is: 
"How to get rid of such automatically added option?

Is it possible to do this without separating compilation and link commands?".

Content of the main.c file:

```
int main()
{
    volatile int a=0x7fffffff;
    a = a<<1;
    return a;
}
```

Content of build_gcc_host.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc \
-fsanitize=shift \
main.c \
-o \
main \
-### \
2>&1 \
| \
grep ubsan
```

P.S. 
The "-lubsan" will not be added if to use "-nostdlib" option, but I do need "stdlib".

I simply don't need automatically added "-lubsan".

Comment: Don't use the sanitizer then.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I ought to use it.

Comment: UBSan runtime library contains code to do UBSan initialization, error reporting, etc. You can not use UBSan without it (unless you plan to reimplement libubsan functions inside your program).

Comment: @yugr Thanks for comment. I do really need to use my handler function instead.

Comment: @lollol In that case (unable to use `-nostdlib` but need to disable libubsan) your only choice is calling `ld` explicitly. Or you can keep libubsan but implement your custom handlers (they will override handlers from libubsan).

Comment: @yugr I believe, it is possible to solve mentioned problem in more elegant way.

Comment: @lollol What makes you think so?

Comment: @yugr At list, possibility to use custom -spec file/rule.